# QT: Searching through QTreeView/QFileSystemModel with a QDtring for a QModelIndex index

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, search

I'm working on a custom `QDialog` for the user to choose a directory on the filesystem. I'm using a `QFIleSystemModel` inside a `QTreeView`. Whenever the user selects an item in the `QTreeView` the directory is written to a `QLineEdit`. My problem is I would like to do the opposite of-sorts by expanding through the `QTreeView` nodes by taking the typed text and... well... obviously expanding the nodes if the text typed is an existing, absolute path.

[image: Just a look at the QDialog]

I've searched for quite a few variations of my problem(although I know it's very loaded) and looked through a lot of the documentation of the classes but I can't find anything to really help me. I'm guessing I need to use `QTreeView::expand(const QModelIndex)` to expand them after finding but searching through the index is my biggest problem as of now. I'm open for any suggestions and any help is truly appreciated. Thank you in advanced and sorry for making such a wall of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> searching through the index is my biggest problem as of now

And index is just a "pointer" to an item in the model. You can't search "through" it, because there is nothing "in" an index. It's just a pointer to exactly one item.

You should search through the **model**. The `index(const QString & path)` method does that for you. Given a path, it returns an index into the element at the end of the path. You can then iterate upwards to extend the items:

```
// ...because QModelIndex::operator= doesn't exist
QModelIndex & assign(QModelIndex & dst, const QModelIndex & src) {
  dst.~QModelIndex();
  new (&dst) QModelIndex(src);
  return dst;
}

void extend(const QString & path, QTreeView * view) {
  auto fs = qobject_cast<QFileSystemModel*>(view->model());
  if (!fs) return;
  auto idx = fs->index(path);
  // ascend up from the child item and expand items in the tree
  while (idx.isValid()) {
    view->expand(idx);
    assign(idx, idx.parent());
  }
}
```

You can use this method with the last item removed from the path as well, since - presumably - the last item might not be valid, and thus `fs->index` might fail.

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry about the mistake. I must have missed the `index(const QString & path)` method in the documentation. I'm not totally confident in my knowledge of everything that is happening but I will study it all over. Again thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Have you check here?

[Model/View Programming][Insert and delete rows in QTreeView]

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html 
[QTreeView & QAbstractItemModel & insertRow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586493/qtreeview-qabstractitemmodel-insertrow)

As base design principle, View only render the data.You should not expect to modify the data via View directly.

Comment: No I don't want to modify the data. I just want to search through the data and expand the nodes of the tree accordingly.